# More than one MATCH/AGAINST clause becomes too slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-text-search

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    gtd_items.*
FROM
    gtd_items
LEFT JOIN gtd ON gtd_items.gtd = gtd.id
     JOIN names importers ON gtd.importer = importers.id
     JOIN names exporters ON gtd.exporter = exporters.id
WHERE
    MATCH (description) AGAINST ('motor' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND
    MATCH (exporters.name) AGAINST ('khs' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND 
    type = 'ИМ'
ORDER BY gtd.date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 25;
```

If I remove one of the `MATCH/AGAINST` clauses (any one), the query is very fast. When I look at the stats I noticed that it only examines ~6,000 rows.

However, when I add the second `MATCH/AGAINST` clause, somehow it examines 700,000 rows, and query becomes very slow. To me it's counter-intuitive - if one `MATCH/AGAINST` clause examines 6000 rows, due to the second AND clause number of rows examined should've decreased further!!!

What's happening here? Following is result of EXPLAIN, though to me it explains nothing:

```
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: exporters
   partitions: NULL
         type: fulltext
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fulltext_index
          key: fulltext_index
      key_len: 0
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: gtd_items
   partitions: NULL
         type: fulltext
possible_keys: fk_data_logs_gtd_idx,description
          key: description
      key_len: 0
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: gtd
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_gtd_names1_idx,fk_gtd_names2_idx,type_idx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: xray.gtd_items.gtd
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: importers
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: xray.gtd.importer
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
```

Thank you!

Comment: What tables are `description` and `type` in??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Which version of MySQL?